# Titanium iOS - give picker transparent background

Tags: titanium

I'm trying to make the UI.Picker element have a transparent background in iOS7 but it always white.

I've tried:

```
backgroundColor:'Transparent'
```

and

```
translucent: true
```

to no avail.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` (note the lower-case 't')

The Colors section from [Ti.UI](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI) documentation should describe in more detail how to specific a color for the background.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, I've tried using rgba on the backgroundColor, also I've tried setting COLOR_UNDER_PAGE_BACKGROUND, COLOR_SCROLLVIEW_BACKGROUND to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you can't change the background or text color of a picker. Therefore, you have to implement your own style and define the colors there.

A hint how to change the text color is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832782/changing-android-picker-font-color-on-titanium-appcelerator).