# Change the Picker Row Title from black to white

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

How can i change the Picker Row title from black to white at Android? i tried with TSS and in the XML with properties with no success.

XML

```
<Alloy>
    <View top="80" height="70">
        <Label class="calendarViewDayDay" top="5" left="10" color="#FFFFFF" text="L('Rooms')"></Label>
        <Picker id="Numberpicker2" top="20" left="10">
            <PickerColumn>
                <PickerRow title="1" />
                <PickerRow title="2" />
                <PickerRow title="3" />
                <PickerRow title="4" />
                <PickerRow title="5" />
                <PickerRow title="6" />
                <PickerRow title="7" />
                <PickerRow title="8" />
                <PickerRow title="9" />
                <PickerRow title="10" />
            </PickerColumn>
        </Picker>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing Android picker font color on titanium appcelerator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832782/changing-android-picker-font-color-on-titanium-appcelerator)

Comment: May I recommend changing the proper answer? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to change the color is to use custom Android theme. You have to add your style as mentioned [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes%20/here), then put the code above inside your style file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItem</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MySpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">your_color_in_hex</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: great addition to the question. This is, in fact, the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

This is only available on Windows and MobileWeb as the docs say:
https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.PickerRow-property-color